# Content is stretching beyond the wrapper's boundaries... (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my website and I can't seem to figure out why it's doing what it is doing. The issue is that the text in the content area is stretching beyond the wrapper. I'm sure it's a very simple mistake that I'm overlooking and I'm hoping some fresh eyes can spot my mistake. I highlighted in the image where it overflows. Thanks! Garrett

Site: http://thinkgarrett.com/hello/index.php

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi you are not clearing about the div section you are using in CSS I think it may help you in somewhat 

div#wrapper { overflow:hidden; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you are not clearing the div floats. This will solve your issue for cross browsers.

Update CSS:

```
div#wrapper {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `div` with class `post` is currently a 0 pixel line, not concerned with its content.

Change the display type of `post` to `inline-block`:

```
.post {
    width: 720px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS...

```
#latestPost {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Elements do not expand to contain floated children, unless you explicitly make it (using one of the many clearfix techniques).